# How to call sth. else beside the default constructor for a class with the new[] - Operator

Tags: c++, class, constructor, initialization, new-operator

How can I call sth. else then the default constructor to initialize an array of typ Class with the new[]-Operator.

```
class Class{
...
}

//this only calls the default Constructor of the class
//but I want to initialize the class with my own defined
//constructor passing various arguments to the constructor 

Class* pClass = new Class[100];
```

Thanks & Cheers

Sebastian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than using `new`, I would suggest using `std::vector`, then you can use whichever constructor you'd like.

For example if you have two versions of your constructor

```
Class();           // default
Class(int, bool);  // some other
```

Then you can say

```
std::vector<Class> classes{100, Class{5, true}};
```

This will make a `vector` with 100 elements, which each call your parameterized constructor with whatever arguments you want.